# Internal hard disk not found

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 14R 5421, which I got in April 2013. Recently while turning on the laptop, a message would appear: "Internal hard disk not found, to resolve this issue try to reseat the drive." I don't really do that because I'm afraid i might ruin something inside, considering this is a 4 year old laptop. I've read somewhere that disabling secure boot mode solves this issue. How do I solve this issue? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it worked before, its probably not secureboot. If the *system* tells you to  reseat the drive, its a good idea to try. I've done hard drive replacements a few times without a service manual and its not rocket surgery. Besides *the computer is telling you do do this*. It isn't that dangerous.

Just grab a copy of the *[owner's manual](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-14r-5421/manuals)* from dell. Its a pretty trivial process, and the manual covers removing the cover, and the hard drive tray,as well as replacing them. Reseat the drive as instructed.  If its still not detected, try the hard drive elsewhere to see if its really dead, and replace it if needed.

While not as easy as a desktop, most modern laptops are not all that hard to work on or fragile. If you're still worried, its a 10 minute job for any decent tech.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to add some more info. When this error occurs, I just shut down the laptop and turn it on again, and the error is gone. Typically this error occurs in maybe 1/20 (?) times I turn on my laptop. I'm worried that it could be a hard drive failure, based on but I check SMART readings thru HD Sentinel and it shows 100%, but some say SMART data is not that reliable. Does this error also mean that my hard drive is failing?

Comment: tbh, if a hard drive was randomly dropping out, I would *certainly* make sure I had backups - its a potential sign of the sort of failure SMART would't pick up